# Create react native project with init command

Tags: android, react-native, sdk

I'm trying to create a new project with `react-native init NewProject` command.
The project was succesfully created but when I try to run project on genymotion android emulator with : `react-native run-android` I get the following output:

```
>C:\IdeaProjects\proj>react-native run-android

Scanning folders for symlinks in C:\IdeaProjects\proj\node_modules (56ms)
JS server already running.

Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug)...

Observed package id 'platform-tools' in inconsistent location 'C:\Android\Sdk\platform-tools' (Expected 'C:\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\platform-tools')     

Observed package id 'platform-tools' in inconsistent location 'C:\Android\Sdk\platform-tools' (Expected 'C:\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\platform-tools')

Observed package id 'platform-tools' in inconsistent location 'C:\Android\Sdk\platform-tools' (Expected 'C:\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\platform-tools')

Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.2 in C:\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\licenses

License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.2 accepted.

Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.2".

>Warning: Trying to install into C:\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\build-tools\23.0.2\ but package "Android SDK Platform-Tools" already exists at C:\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\. It must be deleted o
r moved away before installing into a child directory.

Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 23 in C:\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\licenses

License for package Android SDK Platform 23 accepted.

Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 23".

>Warning: Trying to install into C:\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\platforms\android-23\ but package "Android SDK Platform-Tools" already exists at C:\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\. It must be deleted
 or moved away before installing into a child directory.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to install the following SDK components:
  [Android SDK Platform 23, Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.2]
  Please install the missing components using the SDK manager in Android Studio.
```

I've already succesfully installed:

- *Android SDK Platform 30*
- *Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.2*

Is someone who can take a look please ? I read some topics but without success..

Answer (score 0):

There's very good documentation [available here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html). See the "Building Projects With Native Code" section here.

You might need to setup `node`, `watchman`, and a bunch of other dependencies like `python2`, `react-native-cli`. There are some other configurations too, depending on whether you're using Mac or Windows.

You might wanna take a look at [Create-React-Native-App](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app) too. It's the most recommended way to get started easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can't build new SDK with old build tools. The major version of build tools should be not smaller then SDK. Example of working setup:

- Android SDK Platform 25
- Android SDK Build-Tools 25.0.3